# marker getmap error in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-api-3

Got some problem with the getmap in google maps v3.
I have decalred the myMarker outside of the functions with `var myMarker = [];`     but still get this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

The problem is when i call the function Locatieknop.

Can someone help me out ? Thanks!

```
function MijnLocatie() {
    displayLocation = function(position) {
      myMarker = 0,
        // Container voor de latlon locaties
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        if (!myMarker) {
            // GPS icoon
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'images/bluedot_retina.png',
                null,
                null,
                new google.maps.Point(8, 8),
                new google.maps.Size(17, 17) 
            );

            // Nieuwe marker aanmaken
            myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                flat: true,
                icon: image,
                map: live.map,
                optimized: false,
                position: myLatLng,
                title: 'Mijn locatie',
                visible: true
            });

            // Markers updaten
        } else {
            myMarker.setPosition(myLatLng);
        }

    },

    useragent = navigator.userAgent;

// IPhone en Android ondersteuning
if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') !== -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') !== -1) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        displayLocation,
        handleError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            maximumAge: 30000,
            timeout: 27000
        }
    );

// Browsers met statische locatie
} else if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, handleError);
}
}

function Locatieknop() 
{
try
{
   if (!myMarker || !myMarker.getMap()) 
   {
       MijnLocatie()
   }
   else 
   {
       myMarker.setMap(null);
   }
}
catch(e)
{
  MijnLocatie();
}
}
```

Comment: not your problem, but the google.maps.MarkerImage class was deprecated a while ago, replaced by the google.maps.Icon anonymous object definition.

Comment: Ah, so there is no solution for this problem ?

Comment: I have fixed it. I have edited the code above with the working version! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check if the marker exists before checking the map:

```
function Locatieknop() 
{
    try
    {
       if (!myMarker || !myMarker.getMap()) 
       {
           MijnLocatie()
       }
       else 
       {
           myMarker.setMap(null);
       }
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      MijnLocatie();
   }
}
```

Comment: Still got the error! Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: On which line are you getting this error? I cannot see where you are calling Locatieknop();  if the file that function is in referenced correctly? - can you add a JS Fiddle?

Comment: This line:              myMarker.setPosition(myLatLng);

Comment: position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude have values and the values are not turned around e.g. lat is long and long is lat.  And make sure

Comment: There is nothing turned around, but without the function of the toggle the function of the marker is working correct.

Comment: Got it working now, was forgotten to add `myMarker = 0,` in the beginning of the function! Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

when the marker hasn't been created yet(isn't a `google.maps.Marker`) he doesn't have a method `getMap`, what will result in an error.

You may use a try/catch-statement:

```
function Locatieknop() {
   try{
       if (myMarker.getMap() === null) {
            MijnLocatie()
        } else {
            myMarker.setMap(null);
        }
    }
    catch(e){
      MijnLocatie();
    }
}
```